# Email to Outlook group is arriving with no FROM

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have an automated SQL task that sends an email using SMTP, to an Outlook group with 36 recipients.  Most of the people get the email and can reply to it with no problem.  Some do not get it.  Testing has showed the common theme to be the email arrives with no FROM address, so it fails some 'bounce back' test and never gets into the network.

Anyone seen such a thing, or is this more likely to be happening in the SQL server?

Comment: Whatever (php?) statement is sending the mail needs to include the "from" header, it's not really standard.  That's only the first and easiest problem to resolve tho-- there may be other issues with mail headers.

Comment: The email is created by an SSIS package and there is an valid email address in the FROM space.

Comment: You should contact Microsoft support services about SSIS generating emails that appear not to have a "from" header.   Like I said tho, "from" from the SMTP server point of view is not really a standard required header, except it is because mail without it will be targeted as spam somewhere along the way.  It's possible that the SSIS package thinks it's talking to an Exchange server via SMTP, Exchange in most configs will add a FROM header based on the account used to authenticate.  Anyway the first problem you're facing is email headers missing "from", likely an SSIS configuration issue.